# Fixed element does not obey parent with overflow hidden in Mozilla

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have multiple banners with background images where I want to use background-attachment fixed. 
Since background-attachmed fixed lags in Chrome I put the background in a fixed div to bypass this.

It works in Safari and Chrome but not in Mozilla and I cant figure out why.

Any options or clues on how to solve this?

Example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGXZYo

```
.block .banner {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 140px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.parallax {
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;

    z-index: -1;

    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);

    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Fixed elements do not obey parent. Period.

Comment: So why does it work in Safari / Chrome? and what approach would be best to get the same effect in Mozilla then.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

to

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
transform: translateZ(0);
```